# duplicate packets in wireshark during playback

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I'm writing and testing a script that digs into UDP network traffic and looks for certain data values in each packet. To do all this development while I'm at my desk--not connected to the physical network hardware, I'm playing a pcap using Colasoft Packet Player onto a virtual NIC (Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter) that I created so I can run the pcap over and over while I develop my utility.

When I look at the traffic in Wireshark, every packet is duplicated once. It's like the virtual NIC (or something) is sending the packet back.

When I open the pcap in Wireshark instead of capturing the playback from Colasoft, there are no duplicated packets. Also, when connected to that actual hardware that was connected to create the original pcap, there are no duplicates during live capture in Wireshark.

This seems like a setting on the virtual NIC, but I can't find anything that fixes my issue in the adapter settings.

I've also connected another computer to the physical NIC on my computer, and I have the same issue.

Should I try a different packet player?

Comment: It looks like this could be happening because I'm using a loopback adapter. chatGPT FTW. What's interesting is that it still happens when I'm connected directly to the other computer using the physical NIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Colasoft, but have a few ideas on pcap playback.
Are the packets really identical? You may have the same content being sent to multiple destination addresses.
How are you sampling the playback? Are you sampling at multiple points?
Do you have network equipment involved in your test?
Is this a test with physical equipment or is the whole test simulated?

Comment: They are identical. I updated my question with a screenshot. I'm playing the pcap through a physical ethernet port that is connected to a beaglebone that I just took out of the box. I just needed something connected. I had a similar issue with the virtual NIC, but the multicast packets didn't duplicate--only the regular 10.10.10.120 UDP packets were duplicated.

Comment: Are you sampling on multiple interfaces? Does your device repeat the traffic back to the source computer? Maybe you are capturing it when sending and when it returns? The fact that multicast doesn't duplicate is interesting because routers won't send multicast out until someone subscribes to it (which you probably are not doing).

Comment: As far as the multicast goes, I wouldn't think subscription matters to Wireshark, because it's looking for anything and everything. It's UDP if that matters. I think the fact that the virtual NIC has duplicates should rule out replies/returns... Honestly if my python program can handle the double packets I might just ignore it because the real hardware doesn't duplicate.

Comment: I rephrased the question, to hopefully make it better. I ended up writing my utility to deal with the duplicate packets, but now I need to optimize my code, and I can't do that if I have to deal with these duplicate packets. To answer some of your questions better: at the moment, I'm only looking at the playback in Wireshark--that's where I'm seeing the duplicate packets. Right now, there is no network equipment except the virtual NIC mentioned in my revised question. When I do connect to the hardware that originally created the pcap, there are no duplicates.

Comment: It looks like this could be happening because I'm using a loopback adapter. chatGPT FTW. What's interesting is that it still happens when I'm connected directly to the other computer using the physical NIC.